# How do I add commas in data values

Tags: javascript, php, graph, highcharts

I need to add commas in the data values to display from 123456 to 123,456. I have tried searching numerous forums and supports but I just don't understand what I need to do.

This is the current script code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {

    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'line',
            marginRight: 130,
            marginBottom: 25
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Graph Title',
            x: -20 //center
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: 'Source: Name and site www.url.com',
            x: -20
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Jul-12', 'Aug-12', 'Sep-12', 'Oct-12', 'Nov-12', 'Dec-12',
                'Jan-13', 'Feb-13', 'Mar-13', 'Apr-13']
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Price'
            },
            plotLines: [{
                value: 0,
                width: 1,
                color: '#7c1440'
            }]
        },
        tooltip: {
            valueSuffix: ''
        },
        legend: {
            layout: 'vertical',
            align: 'right',
            verticalAlign: 'top',
            x: -10,
            y: 100,
            borderWidth: 0
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'HERC Index Value',
            data: [230570, 231055, 231055, 232325, 232914, 241636, 241748, 241748, 242330, 242633]

        }]
    });
});


</script>
```

I need the 'data:' values to display as: data: [230,570, 231,055, 231,055, 232,325, 232,914, 241,636, 241,748, 241,748, 242,330, 242,633].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that so far, many answers are very overly complicated.

Clarification of what your end result need is will be very helpful.

However, I am going to go out on a limb and suggest that what you need is not commas in your data values that the chart will use, but a formatted number displayed on the data label, tool tip, or axis label.

If that's the case, you can use a combination of the appropriate formatter for whichever of those areas you want to affect the display of:

- http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#tooltip.formatter
- http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.series.dataLabels.formatter
- http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#yAxis.labels.formatter

and the numberFormat function:

http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Highcharts.numberFormat%28%29

If I misunderstand your need, please clarify.

Answer (score 0):

In Highcharts, your data format need to be number, not string. However, why can't you use simple format with point:

```
data: [230.570, 231.055, 231.055, 232.325, 232.914, 241.636, 241.748, 243.748, 242.330, 242.633]
```

Ant then, when displaying Highcharts, display comma instead: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#lang.decimalPoint

Answer (score -1):

Use [`Array.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), it will create a new list from another with some conditions you want.

```
var arr = [230570, 231055, 231055, 232325, 232914, 241636, 241748, 241748, 242330, 242633],
    parsed = arr.map(function(element, index, array) {
        var string = element.toString(),
            part1 = string.substring(0, 3),
            part2 = string.substring(3);
        return part1 + "," + part2;
    });
alert(parsed);
```

Since it is not fully supported you can also do this with a `for` loop, define `element` as `arr[i]` and you're done!

```
var arr = [230570, 231055, 231055, 232325, 232914, 241636, 241748, 241748, 242330, 242633],
    parsed = [];
for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    var string = arr[i].toString();
        part1 = string.substring(0, 3),
        part2 = string.substring(3);
    parsed.push(part1 + "," + part2);
}
alert(parsed);
```

The modified data will look like this:

```
var data = [230570, 231055, 231055, 232325, 232914, 241636, 241748, 241748, 242330, 242633],
    parsed = data.map(function (element, index, array) {
        var string = element.toString(),
            part1 = string.substring(0, 3),
            part2 = string.substring(3);
        return part1 + "," + part2;
    }),
    obj = {
        chart: {
            type: 'line',
            marginRight: 130,
            marginBottom: 25
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Graph Title',
            x: -20 //center
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: 'Source: Name and site www.url.com',
            x: -20
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Jul-12', 'Aug-12', 'Sep-12', 'Oct-12', 'Nov-12', 'Dec-12',
                'Jan-13', 'Feb-13', 'Mar-13', 'Apr-13']
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Price'
            },
            plotLines: [{
                value: 0,
                width: 1,
                color: '#7c1440'
            }]
        },
        tooltip: {
            valueSuffix: ''
        },
        legend: {
            layout: 'vertical',
            align: 'right',
            verticalAlign: 'top',
            x: -10,
            y: 100,
            borderWidth: 0
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'HERC Index Value',
            data: parsed
        }]
    };
$('#container').highcharts(obj);
```

Remember that `parsed` will be an array of strings, because commas in lists are used to define new elements!

Comment: If I put that in I am getting an error on the first line. Any ideas? thanks

Comment: Yes my bad, try to do the last thing I put, it should work. Remember to create and fill the array `parsed` before passing it to the object

Comment: I really appreciate your help but it all just doesn't make sense to me. What do I put where? Sorry.

Comment: You should understand it, it is basic JS. Anyway, edited again, put the whole script(even if it is not the purpose of SO)

Comment: I did say in the question that I have no real understanding of it. I have copied and pasted in place but am getting a blank screen. Thank you for your time.

Comment: What is the console telling you?

Comment: Well that will be a problem with highcharts, I can't help you with these few informations

Comment: Thanks for your time. Appreciate the effort.